# Aplicar por defecto un 0 en el display de mi calculadora

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Actualmente tengo estos botones y un H1 simple para mostrar la funcionalidad de ellos.
Necesito poner en la pantalla por defecto un 0, y que luego de presionar un botón este 0 se sustituya por el número de botón que presioné.

```
    class App extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = { valueToRender: '' };
            this.renderValue = this.renderValue.bind(this);
        }

        renderValue(value) {
            this.setState({ ...this.state, renderValue: value });
        }

        render() {
            return (
                <div className="CR">
                    <div className="calc-wrapper">
                        <div>
                        <h1>{this.state.renderValue}</h1>
                        </div>
                        <div className="cr-row">
                            <Button value={7} renderValue={this.renderValue} />
                            <Button value={8} renderValue={this.renderValue} />
                            <Button value={9} renderValue={this.renderValue} />
                            <Button value="/" renderValue={this.renderValue} />
                        </div>
    export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Bienvenido.

No sé realmente para qué estás haciendo dicha acción, pero tal y como lo planteas... puede ser algo tal que así:

[CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflowdoubt-odn9k)

Espero que te ayude.

Comment: Realmente, así me lo pidieron. Estoy utilizando hooks y no sé como implementarlo de esa forma. Aún así, gracias por tu respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Al momento de inicializar tu state, la propiedad renderValue inicialízala en 0.
El código quedaria algo asi

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { renderValue: 0 };
    this.renderValue = this.renderValue.bind(this);
  }

  renderValue(value) {
    this.setState({ ...this.state, renderValue: value });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="CR">
        <div className="calc-wrapper">
          <div>
            <h1>{this.state.renderValue}</h1>
          </div>
          <div className="cr-row">
            <button value={7} renderValue={this.renderValue} />
            <button value={8} renderValue={this.renderValue} />
            <button value={9} renderValue={this.renderValue} />
            <button value="/" renderValue={this.renderValue} />
          </div>
        </div> 
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```